# How to localize text with including Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, localization

I have text to localize like this

```
<p>Please enter your user name and password. @Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Register, "Register") if you don't have an account. </p>
```

Very often there is an ActionLink in the text.

Can I use something like {0} for the whole ActionLink

```
@string.Format(Resources.LogOn_Enter_Message, Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Register, "Register"))
```

*(this doesn't work because the link becomes a string)*
or do I have to divide the paragraph into 2 parts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format(Resources.LogOn_Enter_Message, Html.ActionLink(@Resources.Register, "Register")))
```

And store your localized string:

```
 <p>Please enter your user name and password. {0} if you don't have an account. </p>
```

Comment: Gaaah I was so close :-) Thx.